# QMediaPlayer QML Binding Issue

Tags: c++, qt, qml, media, qmediaplayer

I'd like to implement a QMediaPlayer video stream that will be shown on QML. I tried to extend the QMediaPlayer class and created below MyMediaPlayer class. I instantiate this class in my main.cpp file to show it on GUI. Even though there are no errors, the video isn't visible on the QML window. Where is my fault?

**mymediaplayer.cpp**

```
#include "MyMediaPlayer.h"

MyMediaPlayer::MyMediaPlayer(QObject* parent, Flags flags): QMediaPlayer(parent, flags)
{
}

void MyMediaPlayer::setVideoSurface(QAbstractVideoSurface* surface)
{
    qDebug() << "Changing surface";
    m_surface = surface;
    setVideoOutput(m_surface);
}

QAbstractVideoSurface* MyMediaPlayer::getVideoSurface()
{
    qDebug() << "Surface Got";
    return m_surface;
}
```

**mymediaplayer.h**

```
#ifndef MYMEDIAPLAYER_H
#define MYMEDIAPLAYER_H
#include <QMediaPlayer>

class MyMediaPlayer: public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractVideoSurface* videoSurface READ getVideoSurface WRITE setVideoSurface )

public:
    MyMediaPlayer(QObject * parent = 0, Flags flags = 0);

public slots:
    //virtual void play(const QString& strFile);
    void setVideoSurface(QAbstractVideoSurface* surface);
    QAbstractVideoSurface* getVideoSurface();

private:
    QAbstractVideoSurface* m_surface;
};

#endif // MYMEDIAPLAYER_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
 MyMediaPlayer* player = new MyMediaPlayer();


engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mediaplayer", player);

QQuickView view;
view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mediaplayer", player);

player->setMedia(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/1.mp4")));
qDebug() << "media set";
player->play();
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

**main.qml**

```
VideoOutput {
        z: 1000
        id: videooutput
        width: 320
        height: 240
        source: mediaplayer
    }
```

Comment: Uhm...you would probably have a look to the `MediaPlayer` type and set your custom media object via the [`mediaObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#mediaObject-prop) property.

Comment: Does "no error" mean that your property setter is being called?